# Instert into table when the table is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this code to update a value in the database, but this only works if there is already something in the database. is it possible to check if the database is empty first and if its empty INSTERT something into the databse, else just update it with this code.

```
 $name = $_POST['example'];
        if (isset($_POST['example'])) {
            $sql = 'UPDATE `table` SET `column` = "' . $name . '"';
            $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->rowCount();
        }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin

Comment: phpMyAdmin is s not a database. It is a tool. Which database are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: @Dharman Mysql, and yes i know but i had to try this first

Comment: Can you be more specific? You tried what?

Comment: it seems that the solution you sent doesnt work for me, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. It's working for you.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['example'];
    if (isset($_POST['example'])) {
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from `table` where `column` = "' . $name . '"';
        $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            $sql = 'UPDATE `table` SET `column` = "' . $name . '"';                
        } else {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES("' . $name . '")';
        }
        $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }        
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare stmt for prevent sql injection like:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['example'];
    if (isset($_POST['example'])) {
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from `table` where `column` = ?';
        $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            $sql = 'UPDATE `table` SET `column` = ?';                
        } else {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES(?)';
        }
        $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }        
?>
```